# Using pandas to create frequency tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas DataFrame where some of the values are lists of dictionaries:

```
name, array_of_dict
=============
A, [{date: '..', "is_done": True},  {date: '..', "is_done": True},  {date: '..', "is_done": True}]
B, [{date: '..', "is_done": True},  {date: '..', "is_done": True},  {date: '..', "is_done": True}]
C, [{date: '..', "is_done": True},  {date: '..', "is_done": False}]
A, [{date: '..', "is_done": False}, {date: '..', "is_done": True}]
A, [{date: '..', "is_done": False}]
```

I am trying to get the frequency of rows with `is_done = True` and `is_done = False`.

I have first tried

```
print(df.groupby('name').size())
```

which gives me

```
A: 3
B: 1
C: 1
```

so I though I could use the same function to find the frequency of the variables in the dictionaries:

```
print(df.groupby('array_of_dict.is_done').size())
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do analysis using the variables in the arrays of dictionaries?

Comment: Can you show what you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
In [1274]: pd.Series([x['is_done'] for x in df.array_of_dict for x in x]).value_counts()
Out[1274]:
True     8
False    3
```